# Find P(X<Y<Z) in R

Tags: r, function, for-loop

I want to find the `P(X<Y<Z)` in `r`. For each value of `z_i`, I want to check whether it satisfies the conditions or not. I demonstrated the problem below. Here I used the `ifelse` function in `r`. I don't how to put multiple statements within `ifelse`. When I type `ifelse(z[i]>y>x, 1, 0)` I get errors. I want to know how to include this.

```
x = c(1,1)
y = c(2,2)
z = c(3,3)


value = NULL
n1 = length(x)
n2 = length(y)
n3 = length(z)
for(i in 1: length(z)){
  value[i] = sum (ifelse(z[i]>y & z[i]> x & y > x, 1, 0))  
}
value
```

The desired output should be `4 4`. But the above code gives `2 2`. Thanks in advance.

Comment: So what's wrong with your current code? Are you expecting some different output? If so, what exactly are you expecting. The R language syntax doesn't support multiple inequality expressions like `z[i]>y>x`, you need to break them apart and "and" them like you've already done. So `z[i]>y & z[i]>x`. Since you are using `x` and `y` as vectors you'll want to use the vectorized version of "and" `&` rather than the shirt-circuiting version `&&`.

Comment: @MrFlick, thanks. I also want to check ``y>x`` at the same time. For a given ``z`` value, I want to check whether it is greater or not for all ``y>x``.

Comment: You can add another "and" `z[i]>y & z[i]>x & y > x`. You can combine and's and or's, you cannot string together inequities though. It would be helpful if you actually included the desired output for the sample input to make it clear how to test possible solutions.

Comment: @MrFlick, I just updated the code. As you can see, the output is ``2 2``. But it should be ``4 4``.  I am not sure how to fix it. Thanks.

Comment: I don't understand how the output is supposed to be 4. Your vectors only have two values. It seems therefore the answer should be between 0-2 for each element of z. Plus if you are trying to find probabilities then it would seem you want an answer between 0-1. I'm afraid I just can't follow what you are trying to d.

Comment: @MrFlick These are combinations for the first ``4``:  ``z1>y1>x1, z1>y1>x2, z1>y2>x1, z1>y2>x2``. Similar goes for ``z2`` as well. Yes, in this case, the probability is equal to 8/8 = 1.

Comment: Your code currently doesn't do anything to get all possible combinations. That wasn't clear. Something like this should work `expand.grid(x=x, y=y, x=z) |> transform(check=x < y & y < z) |> with(mean(check))`. Taking the mean gives 1 (100%). You could use `sum()` instead to get the count.